# XSL transformation returns blank value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a problem to retrieve my input data when I do an xsl transformation.

This is my original xml input (input xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ns2:pointOfSale 
xmlns:ns2="http://example.net/.." 
mode="CREATE" timestamp="2018-10-12T09:34:53.14+02:00"><ns2:id 
type="AMP">15573</ns2:id></ns2:pointOfSale>
```

This is my output result (output xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="setClients.xsd" encryptedData="N"><client clientID=""></client></clients>
```

this is my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ns2="http://example.net/.."
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="clients">
        <xsl:attribute 
        name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">setClients.xsd</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="encryptedData">N</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="client">
                    <xsl:attribute name="clientID" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns2:id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Like you see, the value of element ID is empty ("")

What's the problem? is it the match() ? Maybe a problem of namespace?

thank you.

Comment: Is your XML accurate? It contains a namespace prefix `ns2:` but it has not been declared with `xmlns:ns2="...."`. Thanks

Comment: The xml is accurate, but I didn't have xmlns:ns2 in my xsl. what's i'm suppose to give as value to "xmlns:ns2 ?

Comment: If you don't have `xmlns:ns2="...."` anywhere in your XML then it will not be namespace compliant, and the XSLT won't be able to process it (because it will not be possible to successfully parse the XML). How are you actually performing the transformation? I would expect you to get an error in this case. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CY for example.

Comment: Ok I see. so suppose we have as original xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ns2:pointOfSale "xmlns:ns2="http://www.xxx.xxxx" 
mode="CREATE" timestamp="2018-10-12T09:34:53.14+02:00"><ns2:id 
type="AMP">15573</ns2:id></ns2:pointOfSale> 
How to retrieve the value of ID in xsl ?

Comment: I made an edit of post. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why `<xsl:value-of select="id"/>` is not returning anything.

Firstly, your template matches `"/"` which is the document node. This is the parent of the `ns2:pointOfSale` node in your XML. The document node does not have `id` as a child, so `<xsl:value-of select="id"/>` will not find anything. To fix this, you should match the root element (`ns2:pointOfSale` in this case) instead

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

The second issue is with namespaces. Assuming there was a namespace declaration in your XML of the form `xmlns:ns2="xxx.xxxx"` you would add the same declaration in your XSLT (on the `xsl:stylesheet` element) and then you could this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ns2:id"/>
```

Without any reference to the namespace in your XSLT, it would be looking for an `id` element in no namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
xmlns:ns2="xxx.xxxx"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="clients">
        <xsl:attribute 
        name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">setClients.xsd</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="encryptedData">N</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="client">
                    <xsl:attribute name="clientID" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns2:id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually, as you are using XSLT 2.0, you could use `xpath-default-namespace` instead, which would mean XSLT would treat any unprefixed element in a `select` expression as part of that namespace.

Try this too....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
xpath-default-namespace="xxx.xxxx"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="clients">
        <xsl:attribute 
        name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">setClients.xsd</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="encryptedData">N</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="client">
                    <xsl:attribute name="clientID" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Better still, use Attribute Value Templates (and avoid the use of `xsl:element`) to simplify the XSLT to this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
xpath-default-namespace="xxx.xxxx"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <clients xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="setClients.xsd" encryptedData="N">
        <client clientID="{id}" />
    </clients>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```